# Errores 404 GET http://localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, localhost

Tengo un error en mi localhost.
El error es que en mi consola(TENGO UN CONSOLE.LOG EN MI ARCHIVO .JS) esta estos dos errores el primero es este `GET http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]` . Lo que no entiendo es que no tengo un favicon.ico.

El segundo error es este `GET http://localhost:3000/Photoslider/page3.jpg [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 43ms]`. Este menos lo entiendo, por que revise mis archivos y todo esta en orden, les agredeceria que me ayuden tengo tiempo intentando solucionarlo pero nada ;( el primer error no afecta en nada(`GET http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]`). Pero el segundo si(GET http://localhost:3000/Photoslider/page3.jpg [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 43ms])

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi there! my error is that when I go to my localhost: 3000, and open my console, I get two errors which are, GET http: // localhost: 3000 / favicon.ico [HTTP / 1.1 404 Not Found 0ms] and the other error is GET http: // localhost: 3000 / Photoslider / page3.jpg [HTTP / 1.1 404 Not found 43ms]. The first error does not affect me at all, but the second error yes and ... will you say how it affects you? It affects me in my WEBSTORE because an image that is PAGE3 is not displayed. Thank you very much for answering

Comment: Hola @xEmmanuel21, podrias redactar mejor la consulta para que asi la comunidad pueda ayudarte de mejor manera. Te dejo  el link como guia

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hola gracia por responder!. Ok intentare explicarte :).  Cuando abro mi consola en mi WEBSTORE , me sale este error `GET http: // localhost: 3000 / Photoslider / page3.jpg [HTTP / 1.1 404 Not found 43ms]` y quiero solucionarlo , porque gracias a ese error no se me visualiza una imagen

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, existen infinidad de razones por las cuales recibes estos errores, ¿tienes un arcvhivo `favicon` en tu ruta raíz? ¿Qué tecnología manejas del lado servidor? ¿Has habilitado el uso de la carpeta `public` o `assets` para que tus archivos estáticos sean servidos correctamente? ¿Puedes crear un [mcve]? En todo caso, si necesitas agregar más detalles, haz clic en [edit] y ponlos en la pregunta, leer detalles en los comentarios es realmente difícil. Saludos

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda pero ya logre solucionarlo, IGUALMENTE MUCHAS GRACIAS!